# How to map binary data in java class object?

Tags: java

Input data :hexadecimal 64 byte

```
String binaryData="01000076183003104000800180f5010100010100000063000000630000006300000063000000000000000000820000000200b8010307010700640005e1cbe180";
```

Question is to read this binary data and set in class object 
Here is the model

```
public class Transaction_PLUSale {


    public byte opcode;
    public byte[] code=new byte[7];

    public  byte flag1;
    public  byte flag2;
    public byte flag3;
    public byte flag4;
    public byte flag5;
    public short deptnum;
    public byte multi_sell_unit;
    public byte return_type;
    public byte tax_pointer;
    public int qty;
    public int price;
    public int amount;
    public int no_tax_price;
    public int no_tax_amount;
    public int return_surcharge_percent;
    public byte product_code;
    public byte flags;
    public TransactionTail tail;
}
```

I am currently doing this way to set values in each fields.

```
String hexArray[]=  binaryData.split("(?<=\\G..)");
public static void readPLUSalesData(String hexArray[]) {
        Transaction_PLUSale pluSale=new Transaction_PLUSale();
        pluSale.setOpcode(Byte.valueOf(hexArray[0]));

        byte arr[]=new byte[7];
        for(int i=1;i<=7;i++) {
            arr[i-1]=Byte.valueOf(hexArray[i]);
        }
        pluSale.setCode(arr);
        pluSale.setFlag1(Byte.valueOf(hexArray[8]));
        pluSale.setFlag2(Byte.valueOf(hexArray[9]));
        pluSale.setFlag3(Byte.valueOf(hexArray[10]));
        pluSale.setFlag4(Byte.valueOf(hexArray[11]));
        pluSale.setFlag5(Byte.valueOf(hexArray[12]));
        pluSale.setDeptnum((short)Integer.parseInt((hexArray[14]+hexArray[13]),16));
        pluSale.setMulti_sell_unit(Byte.valueOf(hexArray[15]));
        pluSale.setReturn_type(Byte.valueOf(hexArray[16]));;
        pluSale.setTax_pointer(Byte.valueOf(hexArray[17]));
        pluSale.setQty(Integer.parseInt((hexArray[21]+hexArray[20]+hexArray[19]+hexArray[18]),16));
        pluSale.setPrice(Integer.parseInt((hexArray[25]+hexArray[24]+hexArray[23]+hexArray[22]),16));
        pluSale.setAmount(Integer.parseInt((hexArray[29]+hexArray[28]+hexArray[27]+hexArray[26]),16));
        pluSale.setNo_tax_price(Integer.parseInt((hexArray[33]+hexArray[32]+hexArray[31]+hexArray[30]),16));
        pluSale.setNo_tax_amount(Integer.parseInt((hexArray[37]+hexArray[36]+hexArray[35]+hexArray[34]),16));
        pluSale.setReturn_surcharge_percent(Integer.parseInt((hexArray[41]+hexArray[40]+hexArray[39]+hexArray[38]),16));
        pluSale.setProduct_code(Byte.valueOf(hexArray[42]));
        pluSale.setFlags(Byte.valueOf(hexArray[43]));

}
```

It is working fine. But I want it to be generic. So instead of giving byte by byte value. I want to direct map it to class fields.

In .net we are doing the marshalling for same feature that I need.
Here is the example

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, byte[]> s in t)
                    {
//byte array consist of bytes of the above hexadecimal string.
                        Ticket ticket = new Ticket();

                        int count = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Transaction_Coupon));
                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(s.Value);
                        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[count];
                        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms);
                        readBuffer = br.ReadBytes(count);
                        GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(readBuffer, GCHandleType.Pinned);

//here we are mapping byte data to each field
                        Transaction_PLUSale t_plusale = (Transaction_PLUSale)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(Transaction_PLUSale));

}
```

Comment: You could somehow use serialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert binary data, a `byte[]` to a class with fields, there is no memory template to shift the data in. A good solution is using a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), either on a byte array or InputStream.

```
public static void readPLUSalesData(String[] hexArray) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hexArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
         bytes[i] = Byte.parseByte(hexArray[i], 16);
    }

    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN;

    Transaction_PLUSale pluSale=new Transaction_PLUSale();
    pluSale.setOpcode(buf.get());

    byte[] arr[] = new byte[7];
    buf.get(arr);
    pluSale.setCode(arr);
    pluSale.setFlag1(buf.get());
    pluSale.setFlag2(buf.get());
    pluSale.setFlag3(buf.get());
    pluSale.setFlag4(buf.get());
    pluSale.setFlag5(buf.get());
    pluSale.setDeptnum(buf.getShort());
    pluSale.setMulti_sell_unit(buf.get());
    pluSale.setReturn_type(buf.get());
    pluSale.setTax_pointer(buf.get());
    pluSale.setQty(buf.getInt());
    pluSale.setPrice(buf.getInt());
    pluSale.setAmount(buf.getInt());
    pluSale.setNo_tax_price(buf.getInt());
    pluSale.setNo_tax_amount(buf.getInt());
    pluSale.setReturn_surcharge_percent(buf.getInt());
    pluSale.setProduct_code(buf.get());
    pluSale.setFlags(buf.get());
}
```

There exist other solutions, like using reflection, which is inefficient.

I used little endian byte order here, default in java is big endian.

There is the ObjectOutputStream, Serializable, persistence using serialisation.
It stores class data too, so is not the language agnostic format you desire.

While developing with a ByteBuffer is makes sense to check the read position.

If you are interested in XML persistence, JAXB with annotations offers a nice reflection based way, without need of handling every field.

A remark: `Type[] variable` is the preferred notation; `Type var[]` was initially added to java to be compatible with C/C++.